# How I can set onpressed on popup from external

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a CustomDialog and I want to pass a pressed event.
Inside the Custom Dialog

```
final String title, description, buttonText, type;
final void pressedAction; // I'm not sure

  CustomDialog({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.type,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.buttonText,
    @required this.pressedAction,
  });

                  FlatButton(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    color: kAzureDarkColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                    disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
                    splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async{
                      await pressedAction();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      buttonText,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ))
```

In the page where I called this:

```
onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomDialog(
                        pressedAction: //push or pop according to the requirements
                        type: 'w',
                        title: "Success",
                        description:
                            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                        buttonText: "Continue",
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

I would like to parameterize the click event with Push or Pop according to the requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type of `pressedAction` should be `Function`. And since it should take a parameter you can use `Function(dynamic action)`

I wrote an example here:

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => CustomDialog(
              pressedAction: (action) {
                if(action == "push"){
                  //Push here.
                }else{
                  //Pop here
                }
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String action) pressedAction;

  const CustomDialog({Key key, this.pressedAction}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                pressedAction("push");
              },
              child: Text("Push"),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 4),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                pressedAction("pop");
              },
              child: Text("Pop"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```